# eigenvectors shortcut trick

Tags: linear-algebra

how to determine the number of linearly independent eigenvectors corresponding to a repeated eigenvalue , for a given square matrix ? Is there any shortcut method available , to avoid using the whole lengthy procedure?

Comment: The multiplicity of an eigenvalue as a root of the characteristic polynomial ("repeated eigenvalue") is called its *algebraic multiplicity*.  The number of linearly independent eigenvectors for an eigenvalue is called its *geometric multiplicity*.  What shortcuts are possible depends on what information is available, e.g. having the minimal polynomial to compare to the characteristic polynomial.

Answer (score 2):

It's not entirely clear what you're asking.  In particular, what exactly is the information we're given, and what is "the whole lengthy procedure"?

Here's what I think you mean: we are given a matrix $A$, and we know that $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$, but we want to know the number of linearly independent eigenvectors associated with $\lambda$ (that is, we want to know the geometric multiplicity of $\lambda$).

If that's what you mean, then it suffices to note that the number of linearly independent eigenvectors is $\dim \ker (A - \lambda I)$.  That is, it suffices to row-reduce the matrix $A - \lambda I$, and count the number of free columns in the resulting row-echelon form matrix.

For example: consider the matrix
$$
A = \pmatrix{1&0&1&0\\0&1&0&1\\1&0&1&0\\0&1&0&1}
$$
This matrix has $\lambda = 2$ as an eigenvalue.  In order to determine the number of linearly independent eigenvectors, we compute
$$
A - 2 I = \pmatrix{1&0&1&0\\0&1&0&1\\1&0&1&0\\0&1&0&1} - \pmatrix{2&0&0&0\\0&2&0&0\\0&0&2&0\\0&0&0&2} = \pmatrix{-1&0&1&0\\0&-1&0&1\\1&0&-1&0\\0&1&0&-1}
$$
We now row-reduce this matrix to get
$$
\pmatrix{-1&0&1&0\\0&-1&0&1\\1&0&-1&0\\0&1&0&-1} \leadsto 
\pmatrix{1&0&-1&0\\0&1&0&-1\\0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0}
$$
The echelon-form matrix on the right has two pivot columns and **two free columns**.  As such, the the number of linearly independent eigenvectors associated with $\lambda = 2$ is $2$.